# Get UI Element On-Screen Position

Tags: accessibility

I'm looking for a way to fetch child UI element (Button, textbox, combobox) position on screen (does not matter if relative to parent or absolute to desktop).

Is there mechanism available to perform this action in linux (Ubuntu 16 to be more specific)?

Thank you